# Category bitmask for more than one

Tags: sprite-kit

What if I have 50 SpriteKit nodes that each of them has a different categorybitmask and I have a ball if the ball collided with one of those 50 SpriteKit nodes it for example change the color of the the collided SpriteKit to for example green

To achieve this I know I have to write the category bitmask of the SpriteKit node in contact bitmask of the ball

The question is what if if I have 50 SpriteKit nodes how can I or do I have to write all of the 50 SpriteKit nodes in the contact bitmask of the ball

I tried using a loop but I didn’t know how to implement it right

And thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can place many nodes under the same categoryBitmask and assign different names to them.

Example:

```
  enum Collision: UInt32{

     case ball = 1
     case circle = 2
     case box = 4

   }
```

Node Examples:

```
      let node1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "SoccerBall")
      node1.name = "SoccerBall"
      node1.physicsBody =     SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: node1.size.width)

      node1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collision.ball.rawValue
      node1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collision.circle.rawValue | Collision.box.rawValue  
      addChild(node1)


      let node2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TennisBall")
      node2.name = "TennisBall"
      node2.physicsBody =     SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius:node2.size.width)

      node2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collision.ball.rawValue
      node2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collision.circle.rawValue | Collision.box.rawValue  
      addChild(node2)
  
  

   let node3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "CartonBox")
      node3.name = "CartonBox"
      node3.physicsBody =     SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: node.frame.width, height: node.frame.height)

      node3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collision.box.rawValue
      node3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collision.ball.rawValue  
      addChild(node3)


      let node4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "TreasureChest")
      node4.name = "TreasureChest"
      node4.physicsBody =     SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: node.frame.width, height: node.frame.height)

      node4.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = Collision.box.rawValue
      node4.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = Collision.ball.rawValue  

      addChild(node4)
```

In your contact function:

```
 func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact){
    guard let nodeA = contact.bodyA.node else {return}
    guard let nodeB = contact.bodyB.node else {return}

    if nodeA.name == "SoccerBall" && nodeB.name == "CartonBox"{

      //Do Something

    }


    if nodeA.name == "TennisBall" && nodeB.name == "CartonBox"{

      //Do Something 

    }

    if nodeA.name == "SoccerBall" && nodeB.name == "TreasureChest"{

     //Do Something

    }

  }
```

And so on...

Just remember to add the SKPhysicsContactDelegate to you class Gamescene.